# jquery validation alert for selected optiong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I'm trying to validate  combo box's like the below code, I get few alert messages even one condition is true. I needed to get only one alert even one condition is true and other should bordered in red. thank you

```js
$(function() {
  $('#issue-form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    var TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
    var IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_55').val();

    if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '157') {
      alert("Please select an option!");
      $("#issue_custom_field_values_55").css("border", "2px solid red");
      return false;
    }
  });
});


$(function() {
  $('#issue-form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    var TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
    var IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_52').val();

    if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '156') {
      alert("Please select an option!");
      $("#issue_custom_field_values_52").css("border", "2px solid red");
      return false;
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#issue-form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    var TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
    var IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_56').val();

    if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '158') {
      alert("Please select an option!");
      $("#issue_custom_field_values_56").css("border", "2px solid red");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="issue-form">
  <div class="splitcontent">
    <p>
      <select name="issue[status_id]" id="issue_status_id">
        <option value="1">New</option>
        <option value="2">In Progress</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">Solved</option>
        <option value="4">Feedback</option>
        <option value="5">End</option>
        <option value="6">Rejected</option>
      </select>

      <p><label for="issue_custom_field_values_51"><span title="IssueType<" class="field-description">Issue Type</span></label>
        <select name="issue[custom_field_values][51]" id="issue_custom_field_values_51" class="enumeration_cf">
          <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="55">Software Bug</option>
          <option value="56">Enviromental Bug　</option>
          <option value="58">Other Factors</option>
        </select>
      </p>

      <p style="display: block;"><label for="issue_custom_field_values_52"><span title="OrginProcess" class="field-description">Orgin Process</span></label>
        <select name="issue[custom_field_values][52]" id="issue_custom_field_values_52" class="enumeration_cf">
          <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="156">--- 未選択/not entered ---</option>
          <option value="59">１Ａ．ＢＩ</option>
          <option value="60">１Ｂ．ＢＤ</option>
          <option value="61">１Ｃ．ＤＤ</option>
          <option value="62">１Ｄ．ＰＤ</option>
          <option value="63">１Ｅ．Ｃ</option>
        </select>
      </p>

      <p style="display: block;"><label for="issue_custom_field_values_55"><span title="Reason" class="field-description">Reason of Leakage (Design)</span></label>
        <select name="issue[custom_field_values][55]" id="issue_custom_field_values_55" class="enumeration_cf">
          <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="157">--- 未選択/not entered ---</option>
          <option value="79">Poor Quality</option>
          <option value="80">Not Reviewed</option>
          <option value="81">Review Point Leak</option>
          <option value="82">Review, Correction &amp; Confirmation</option>
          <option value="83">Lack of Communication</option>
          <option value="84">Other</option>
          <option value="85">Not Applicable</option>
        </select>
      </p>


      <p style="display: block;"><label for="issue_custom_field_values_56"><span title="Test Process" class="field-description">Test Process that Extract Bug</span></label>
        <select name="issue[custom_field_values][56]" id="issue_custom_field_values_56" class="enumeration_cf">
          <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="158">--- 未選択/not entered ---</option>
          <option value="86">ＵＴ</option>
          <option value="87">ＳＩ1</option>
          <option value="88">ＳＩ2</option>
          <option value="89">ＰＴ</option>
          <option value="90">ＲＴ</option>
        </select>
      </p>

  </div>

</form>
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create">
```

I needed to get the result like this with an alert message when first other values have been selected with an option. I needed an help from the following javascript code changes. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below given code to remove border -

```js
$(function () {
            $('#issue-form input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
                var TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
                var IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_55').val();
                var isAlert = 0;
                if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '157') {
                    isAlert = 1;
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_55").css("border", "2px solid red");
                }
    else{
    $("#issue_custom_field_values_55").css("border", "none");
    }

                TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
                IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_52').val();

                if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '156') {
                    isAlert = 1;
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_52").css("border", "2px solid red");

                }
else{
$("#issue_custom_field_values_52").css("border", "none");
}
                TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
                IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_56').val();

                if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '158') {
                    isAlert = 1;
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_56").css("border", "2px solid red");
                }else
    {
     $("#issue_custom_field_values_56").css("border", "none");
    }
                if (isAlert == "1") {
                    alert("Please select an option!");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="issue-form">
        <div class="splitcontent">
            <p>
                <select name="issue[status_id]" id="issue_status_id">
                    <option value="1">New</option>
                    <option value="2">In Progress</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="3">Solved</option>
                    <option value="4">Feedback</option>
                    <option value="5">End</option>
                    <option value="6">Rejected</option>
                </select>

                <p>
                    <label for="issue_custom_field_values_51"><span title="IssueType<" class="field-description">Issue Type</span></label>
                    <select name="issue[custom_field_values][51]" id="issue_custom_field_values_51" class="enumeration_cf">
                        <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="55">Software Bug</option>
                        <option value="56">Enviromental Bug　</option>
                        <option value="58">Other Factors</option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p style="display: block;">
                    <label for="issue_custom_field_values_52"><span title="OrginProcess" class="field-description">Orgin Process</span></label>
                    <select name="issue[custom_field_values][52]" id="issue_custom_field_values_52" class="enumeration_cf">
                        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="156">--- 未選択/not entered ---</option>
                        <option value="59">１Ａ．ＢＩ</option>
                        <option value="60">１Ｂ．ＢＤ</option>
                        <option value="61">１Ｃ．ＤＤ</option>
                        <option value="62">１Ｄ．ＰＤ</option>
                        <option value="63">１Ｅ．Ｃ</option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p style="display: block;">
                    <label for="issue_custom_field_values_55"><span title="Reason" class="field-description">Reason of Leakage (Design)</span></label>
                    <select name="issue[custom_field_values][55]" id="issue_custom_field_values_55" class="enumeration_cf">
                        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="157">--- 未選択/not entered ---</option>
                        <option value="79">Poor Quality</option>
                        <option value="80">Not Reviewed</option>
                        <option value="81">Review Point Leak</option>
                        <option value="82">Review, Correction &amp; Confirmation</option>
                        <option value="83">Lack of Communication</option>
                        <option value="84">Other</option>
                        <option value="85">Not Applicable</option>
                    </select>
                </p>


                <p style="display: block;">
                    <label for="issue_custom_field_values_56"><span title="Test Process" class="field-description">Test Process that Extract Bug</span></label>
                    <select name="issue[custom_field_values][56]" id="issue_custom_field_values_56" class="enumeration_cf">
                        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="158">--- 未選択/not entered ---</option>
                        <option value="86">ＵＴ</option>
                        <option value="87">ＳＩ1</option>
                        <option value="88">ＳＩ2</option>
                        <option value="89">ＰＴ</option>
                        <option value="90">ＲＴ</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I analysed your java-script and found that your logic require some changes as given below -

```js
$(function () {
            $('#issue-form input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
                var TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
                var IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_55').val();
                var isAlert = 0;
                if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '157') {
                    isAlert = 1;
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_55").css("border", "2px solid red");
                }

                TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
                IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_52').val();

                if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '156') {
                    isAlert = 1;
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_52").css("border", "2px solid red");

                }

                TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
                IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_56').val();

                if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '158') {
                    isAlert = 1;
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_56").css("border", "2px solid red");
                }
                if (isAlert == "1") {
                    alert("Please select an option!");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="issue-form">
        <div class="splitcontent">
            <p>
                <select name="issue[status_id]" id="issue_status_id">
                    <option value="1">New</option>
                    <option value="2">In Progress</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="3">Solved</option>
                    <option value="4">Feedback</option>
                    <option value="5">End</option>
                    <option value="6">Rejected</option>
                </select>

                <p>
                    <label for="issue_custom_field_values_51"><span title="IssueType<" class="field-description">Issue Type</span></label>
                    <select name="issue[custom_field_values][51]" id="issue_custom_field_values_51" class="enumeration_cf">
                        <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="55">Software Bug</option>
                        <option value="56">Enviromental Bug　</option>
                        <option value="58">Other Factors</option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p style="display: block;">
                    <label for="issue_custom_field_values_52"><span title="OrginProcess" class="field-description">Orgin Process</span></label>
                    <select name="issue[custom_field_values][52]" id="issue_custom_field_values_52" class="enumeration_cf">
                        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="156">--- 未選択/not entered ---</option>
                        <option value="59">１Ａ．ＢＩ</option>
                        <option value="60">１Ｂ．ＢＤ</option>
                        <option value="61">１Ｃ．ＤＤ</option>
                        <option value="62">１Ｄ．ＰＤ</option>
                        <option value="63">１Ｅ．Ｃ</option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p style="display: block;">
                    <label for="issue_custom_field_values_55"><span title="Reason" class="field-description">Reason of Leakage (Design)</span></label>
                    <select name="issue[custom_field_values][55]" id="issue_custom_field_values_55" class="enumeration_cf">
                        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="157">--- 未選択/not entered ---</option>
                        <option value="79">Poor Quality</option>
                        <option value="80">Not Reviewed</option>
                        <option value="81">Review Point Leak</option>
                        <option value="82">Review, Correction &amp; Confirmation</option>
                        <option value="83">Lack of Communication</option>
                        <option value="84">Other</option>
                        <option value="85">Not Applicable</option>
                    </select>
                </p>


                <p style="display: block;">
                    <label for="issue_custom_field_values_56"><span title="Test Process" class="field-description">Test Process that Extract Bug</span></label>
                    <select name="issue[custom_field_values][56]" id="issue_custom_field_values_56" class="enumeration_cf">
                        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="158">--- 未選択/not entered ---</option>
                        <option value="86">ＵＴ</option>
                        <option value="87">ＳＩ1</option>
                        <option value="88">ＳＩ2</option>
                        <option value="89">ＰＴ</option>
                        <option value="90">ＲＴ</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your help, can you help me with the border too? to remove if the value already there? can it be done in the same JS code?

Answer (score 1):

Use below given code in this case. Please like my profile if it works for you.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#issue-form input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
                var TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
                var IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_55').val();
                var isAlert = 0;
                if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '157') {
                    isAlert = 1;
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_55").css("border", "2px solid red");
                } else {
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_55").css("border", "none");
                }

                TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
                IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_52').val();

                if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '156') {
                    isAlert = 1;
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_52").css("border", "2px solid red");
                } else {
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_52").css("border", "none");
                }

                TrackID = $('#issue_status_id').val();
                IssueCF = $('#issue_custom_field_values_56').val();

                if (TrackID == '3' && IssueCF == '158') {
                    isAlert = 1;
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_56").css("border", "2px solid red");
                } else {
                    $("#issue_custom_field_values_56").css("border", "none");
                }
                if (isAlert == "1") {
                    alert("Please select an option!");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```